# Can't change font in button that create with xib file Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I've create a UIView in xib file and try to change font in Button in that xib file like this

[xib file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2boW.png)

but when i run my application font didn't chage to font that i expect and i check in debugView it show another font.

[font that show in debug view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfUBO.png)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: the label is the same but i use localize to change language

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change the `Style` from **Plain** to **Default** in the drop down in the screenshot you shared, then you should be able to change the font.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: So you can't change font of a filled button?

Comment: @YaroslavDukal I tried doing the same, in Xcode it was showing the updated font, but on runtime on my phone it was displaying a different font.

Comment: *System* style also allows to change font. And it keeps text Blue as expected.